# A function that respects the Cauchy Riemann Equations

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I m searching for some counter exemples.

1. A function infinitely differentiable  which is not holomorphic but respects the C. R. Equations  (is it possible??)
2. A function infinitely continuous but not holomorphic
3. A function which derivative are not continuous but respects the C. R. Equations
4. A not continuous function but respects the C. R. Equations

For 3. I ve found :
$$  \frac{z^4} {|z|^3}  $$

What do you think?

Comment: What is an infinitely continuous function?

Comment: I dont know how is it called in english... I meant a C^infty function

Comment: 1. No, it is not possible. The Cauchy-Riemann equations imply analiticity for complex-valued functions

Comment: OK. It is called infinitely differentiable.

Comment: Okay thx :) i ll change that

Comment: 1. If $f$ is differentiable and respect C.R. equations then it is analytic and also holomorphic (in it domain). The other way is also true. From wikipedia: "In the field of complex analysis in mathematics, the Cauchy–Riemann equations, named after Augustin Cauchy and Bernhard Riemann, consist of a system of two partial differential equations which, together with certain continuity and differentiability criteria, form a **necessary and sufficient condition** for a complex function to be complex differentiable, that is, holomorphic."

Comment: More over: when you says that $f$ is differentiable what you mean? Complex-differentiable? If a function is complex-differentiable it is holomorphic

Answer (score 0):

For a partial answer to your questions, you should look at the statement of [Looman–Menchoff theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Looman%E2%80%93Menchoff_theorem) and following examples.

Also, there is a great paper: [When is a Function that Satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann Equations Analytic?](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2321164?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) written by **J. D. Gray** and **S. A. Morris**.